# Django City Model

Tags: python, django

My application is going to require that we maintain a list of cities in the database. So the database has a table of zipcodes (the primary key), each of which has a field called city (there is nothing international). I know the mapping is not 1-1 in real life, but we still manage to associate each zip with a primary city.

There are going to be many forms where a user needs to enter a city, and we in turn need to map it to a zipcode. The city entered will need to match one of the cities already in the database (we are going to preload these). How can I indicate that the contents of the choices attribute on the city field should be the contents that already exist in the zipcode table for the city column? Should I assign the choices attribute to a function that returns this data in the appropriate format? Wouldn't this have performance implications? Or should I just precompute a massive file and use that instead? Or do I just forgo using the choices attribute? A little guidance would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: city is a one to many relationship with zipcode.  I believe the USPS has a free dataset.  It is more common to ask for a zipcode which will then define the city. You can use ajax to get a quick turn around to populate the city

Comment: We have a couple different workflows that request location information. When the user signs up, we do ask for a zipcode and do exactly what you're describing. But there are other workflows where it makes far more sense to start with the city/state and map it later to the zipcode. These are the situations I'm struggling with. But then again, some cities map to multiple zipcodes, so I'm not even sure the model I'm suggesting is viable.